# Which law of thermodynamics is broken here?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, energy, energy-conservation, heat-engine

*This question came in the Dhaka university admission exam 18-19.*

A heat engine in each cycle does positive work and loses energy as heat with no heat energy input. Which law of thermodynamics does the engine violate?

(a) Zeroth law

(b) First law

(c) Second law

(d) Third law

**My attempt:**

Let the heat energy gained by the engine from the hot reservoir during the isothermal expansion is $Q_1$, and the heat energy lost to the cold reservoir during the isothermal compression is $Q_2$. Let the positive work done by the engine is $W$. We know,

$$Q_1-Q_2=W$$

$$\text{[According to the question, $Q_1=0$]}$$

$$0-Q_2=W$$

$$-Q_2=W\tag{1}$$

This is an impossibility. To make the impossibility explicit, let us assume $W=2J$ and $Q_2=5J$. Now, $(1)$ becomes

$$-5J=2J$$

Clearly, we have broken a law.

I think that we have broken the first law of thermodynamics. The first law of thermodynamics states the following:

> the law of conservation of energy states that the total energy of an
> isolated system remains constant; it is said to be conserved over
> time.

If positive work was done by the heat engine, then the energy expended by the engine to do work must've come from somewhere (hot reservoir). The engine can't do positive work, i.e., create new energy on its own! If no energy is provided by the hot reservoir, no positive work is possible due to the 1st law of thermodynamics. So, I think the answer will be (b).

---

However, according to the question bank, the answer is (c). Aren't they wrong?

Comment: Oh man these entrance exam questions. I thought India had it bad. Didn't know this existed in Bangladesh too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a good question. Yes, as stated, the engine appears to violate the first law. It can also be claimed that the second law is violated, but this is not that straightforward because some of the various statements of the second law (and their equivalence) rely on the first law, at least implicitly. One such claim might be that since there is no heat input, the efficiency of this engine would be infinite, and hence obviously greater than the Carnot efficiency.

Answer (score -1):

The way the question is worded it appears a heat engine is doing positive work with no heat. That's a violation of the 2nd law since heat can't flow from cold to hot to produce work and expend heat without any heat input.

Comment: "heat can't flow from cold to hot". In my question, heat is not flowing from cold to hot. "expend heat without any heat input." Could you please quote the version of 2nd law of thermodynamics that says this?

Comment: Hi. First I agree it's a terribly worded question. Here is the Lord Kelvin statement of the 2nd Law: "It is impossible for a self-acting machine, unaided by any external agency, to convey heat from one body to another at a higher temperature."  This is the basis for my answer. I interpreted "no  energy input" to mean no heat. Since the engine is operating and "losing energy as heat" . I interpreted that as an attempt to operate a hot engine from a cold reservoir.